# How to get the bluetooth MAC address in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am using pybluez to work with Bluetooth in Raspberry pi. I am trying to get the bluetooth MAC address of Raspberry pi. Is there any way to get the bluetooth MAC address in pybluez.

Answer (score 2):

Using commands library and hciconfig command in shell

```
import commands
cmd = "hciconfig"
device_id = "hci0" 
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
bt_mac = output.split("{}:".format(device_id))[1].split("BD Address: ")[1].split(" ")[0].strip()
print bt_mac
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/commit/38634a16f8ecb2dbcac3e6cc4a12ec713d5f7b8b

Here is the sample to read the local BDADDR.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PyBluez to find your Raspberry Pi's MAC Address:

```
   import re, uuid 
   print(':'.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode())).encode())
```

This should find your Device's MAC Address

Comment: This returns the MAC address of the ethernet device instead of the MAC address of the bluetooth device